# Centripetal Catmull–Rom spline interpolation

Tags: interpolation, spline

I've just finished an implementation of a parametrized (centripetal) Catmull-Rom spline using this formula from wikipedia: *Link in the comment, not enough reputation for more links.*

I'd like to ask this: **Does the algorithm restrict the input data in any way?** Specifically: Do the X-values have to be uniformly distributed? My data will almost never comply with that.

I am asking, because sometimes this appens (notice the weird bit on the left): https://i.stack.imgur.com/18xGf.png. I used these $[X,Y]$ points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HII1H.png

It happens with other implementations I've found on the internet, too, so most likely it isn't an error on my side.

Thanks in advance for any comments or advice!

Comment: Wikipedia source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline#Definition

Comment: Centripetal Catmull-Rom spline does not require the x values to be uniformly distributed. From your picture, it does not look like a normal result of interpolation using centripetal Catmull-Rom spline. Perhaps you have some bugs in your program?

Comment: @fang Well I thought so too at first, but since the other implementation I've found on the internet gives the exact same result, it made me think that this error happened because of some centripetal catmull-rom interpolation's property I don't know about.

Comment: If you also draw the data points with the curve, it will be easier to spot problems as the curve's slope at P_i should be in the direction defined by P_(i-1) and P_(i+1) for Catmull-Rom spline.